# operator[] - why should I not use it?

Tags: c++

I have been told that using the `operator[]` is wrong.

what is the difference between:

```
vector<double> * IDs;
...
IDs->operator[](j) = 1;
```

and:

```
vector<double> * IDs;
...
(*IDs)[j] = 1;
```

Comment: Well, it's more to write... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing at all, they are equivalent.

Two things though

1) `IDs->operator[](j)` is less clear than `(*IDs)[j]`.

2) If you can use `const vector<double>& IDs` instead then not only do you benefit from the even clearer `IDs[j]` but you also gain stability via the fact that you cannot modify the vector using `IDs`.

Remember that one day your code will be maintained by someone less able than you so clarity is important.

Comment: That `const` does not mean "immutability". Not of the IDs and not even of the vector.

Comment: Care to elaborate R. Martinho Fernandes? I like the fact that you can't call non-const member functions on std::vector if your object is marked as const.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=93ceeeae2034b6099a70639b71cebab1-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Comment: Fair play; but you cannot change it via IDs though (unless you cast away the constness). I've edited my answer - I've removed immutability.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of using this operator is so that your object can use the [] in some way that hides the real data structure or data organization within itself but on the outside, provides an array-like interface.

For e.g. both vectors and deques are implemented quite differently and have better performances for different purposes, but on the outside, they both provide the [] so that the user feels like he's using a dynamic array.

So, it's not wrong, but it defeats the purpose.